# Is there any way to allow a view to be automatically "click-throughable" in a Storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uistoryboard

I have a dark overlay I occasionally present over the full tableview, and I'd like to set it up in the Storyboard, but when I do, it obfuscates access to all the views beneath it (AKA all the views).

Setting it to hidden makes it transparent, but you can still click it. Is there any way to make it click-throughable all the time?

Answer (score 3):

Set the property `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` on your dark overlay view and all user touches should pass through.

Edit:
The simple answer is no. You cannot change how interface builder works. Besides, [it's better to do things in code](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/why-i-dont-use-interface-builder), especially when collaborating.

Comment: Not at runtime, I meant when a developer interacts with the Storyboard for a view to be click-throughable.